# vb .net 2015 encoding cannot display special characters

Tags: vb.net, encoding

I have DXF files from various sources and various European languages and I'm having a problem reading in the source file into my application. A DXF file is a text file and can be produced by many types of CAD or similar software. The whole file is read in and saved to an array, the group code is in the first column of the array and the data value in the second column. So I can see the data values in the array when I'm in debug mode.

I've tried using:

```
 For Each sLine In File.ReadLines(strOrgDxfFileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)
```

and

```
 For Each sLine In File.ReadLines(strOrgDxfFileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

I'm using  a computer with a German OS, so I would imagine that when using .Default it would pick up the German code page and hence the German special characters äÄöÖüÜß. But when using two files from different sources sometimes it works and sometimes not.

File 1 using .Default gives "höhenmäßig angepaßt" which is correct.
File 1 using .UTF8 gives "h�henm��ig angepa�t" which is incorrect.

File 2 using .Default gives "BrÃ¼ckenstraÃŸe" which is incorrect.
File 2 using .UTF8 gives "Brückenstraße" which is correct.

I can't find a reliable way of reading in the special characters correctly. I will also be getting DXF files in other languages so it is important that I always get the special characters regardless of language and regardless of the OS the DXF was created in or the OS of the reading computer.

I have been battling with this for a few days now but not getting anywhere. Can anyone offer some advice?

Ben

Comment: A search for "dxf file text encoding" gives some suggestions.

Comment: I had done that before I posted and just repeated it and I find nothing that is of any use for my case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

try this if works let me know

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString))
```

or try it this way

```
Dim converted as Byte() = Encoding.Convert(utf8, Encoding.UTF8, _
                                           Encoding.GetEncoding(28591))
```

If i could get you well and what i thought you are trying to do is, your are trying to read a DXF Auto Card File: the i will ether advice you to use a autocad library or third party library
step to achieve it:
1. visit this link: [Link to download DXF Library](https://netdxf.codeplex.com/) and search for netDxf 1.1.2 and download it.
2.import the library to your project and use this peace of code:

```
public static void Main()
   { 
      // by default it will create an AutoCad2000 dxf version
      DxfDocument dxf = new DxfDocument();
      // add your entities here
      dxf.AddEntity(entity);
      // save to file
      dxf.Save(filename);

      // load file
      DxfDocument dxfLoad = DxfDocument.Load(filename);
   }
```

and let me know if solve your problem.

if its raw file you want in any language try this:

```
Dim strTest = File.ReadAllText("your_german_file.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

or

```
Dim reader As New StreamReader("C:\example.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

because of what @Joel Coehoorn said

Comment: The first code example returns the whole of the file as a single line of question marks. But what I don't understand when I use the following code I actually get the number of lines in the file:
'        Dim lines As New List(Of String)
        If strOrgDxfFileName <> "" Then
            lines.AddRange(ReadAllLines(strOrgDxfFileName))
        End If
        lLines = lines.Count'

With your second line of code I have to prefix Encoding with System.Text and I get an error on "utf8". Where's the string read in from the DXF file?

Comment: okay what is the name of environment your are using for development Sir

Comment: ASCII? He's trying to read German characters and you recommend ASCII?

Comment: No its not ASCII as that doesn't contain the characters ÄäÖöÜüß, nor would it be able to deal with some other special characters in other languages, Not just German, but Spanish, French, Swedish, etc. All I have is a text file. Joel is correct in his thinking.

Comment: I am using Visual Basic .NET 2015.
I don't need any AutoCAD libraries as I am not creating a DXF file, that's the file I receive.
Am I correct in thinking that using 'System.Text.Encoding.Default' will use the code page of the OS on that computer, can that deal with all characters that I might encounter?

Comment: yeah definitely correct it will surely handle all character as its stated in MSDN